# Problem in fetching Email body content in HTML format using PHP

Tags: php, html-parsing

My code(In PHP) is fetching Email, from Inbox wihich is in HTML format, and saving it in an HTML format. while fetching some Extra characters are added to the file.
Example:
the content in EMAIL Body

```
hi there

 1.      hi
 2. hello
 3. bye
```

but when fetched i get

```
hi there

1. =A0=A0=A0=A0 hi
2. hello
3. bye
```

I get extra characters like "=A0=A0=A0=A0". How to get rid of this?

Comment: try using htmlspecialchars_decode()

Comment: no @Grumpy htmlspecialchars_decode did not work!

Comment: how *are* you parsing your HTML?

Comment: i am using IMAP functions to get the contents from INBOX, and the body in form of HTML Documant is saved in an HTML file. (thats what is giving the above problem...)

Answer (score 0):

I think, your mail body is in base64 format. Try to use this function: [base64_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php)

Comment: no, it's not working...the extra characters comes in place of spaces, like in the above example at 1.  hi

Comment: i think that editor might be putting some special characters at space.. or some thing like that...